# Setting Alarm for Particular Timings with Respect to Start Date and End Date of an Event in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-calendar

I am having an Calendar Event with **start date as (24hrs format) 27-Apr-2016 11:00:00 and end date as 29-Apr-2016 11:00:00**. I am having three timings **10:45:00**, **10:30:00** and **10:15:00** which are calculated for alerting the event prior to the actual set timings (i.e 15 mins, 30 mins and 45 mins early to the start date).

Also the alarm must repeat daily for the same prior timings till the end date is reached.

Here is how i tried to do it, How ever the below code does not invoke the alarm nor it repeats daily

In the **MainActivity.java**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Broadcast.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2016,03,27,11,00,00);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(60000*15), pendingIntent); // subtract for 15 mins prior alarm time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(60000*30), pendingIntent); // subtract for 30 mins prior alarm time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(60000*45), pendingIntent); // subtract for 45 mins prior alarm time
```

In the **Broadcast.java**

```
Log.i("Alarm", "Alarm Manager is called");
Toast.makeText(context, new Date().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: In BroadCast.java are you using WakefulBroadcast Recevier?@Waseem

Comment: yes its a class extending BroadcastReceiver @CrazyAndroid

Comment: In that case I request you to extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver because it will guarantee that your CPU will stay awake until you fire the completeWakefulIntent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my sample code, Try this:

Modify the date and time as your need in the below code.

```
 public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION1 = 201;
    public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION2 = 202;
    public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION3 = 203;

     private void repeatNotification() {
        final DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.now();
        dateTime1.hourOfDay().setCopy(7);
        dateTime1.minuteOfHour().setCopy(30);
        dateTime1.secondOfMinute().setCopy(00);
        final Calendar calendarNotifiedTime1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime1.getHourOfDay());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime1.getMinuteOfHour());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime1.getSecondOfMinute());
        calendarNotifiedTime1.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

        final DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.now();
        dateTime2.hourOfDay().setCopy(12);
        dateTime2.minuteOfHour().setCopy(30);
        dateTime2.secondOfMinute().setCopy(00);
        final Calendar calendarNotifiedTime2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarNotifiedTime2.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime2.getHourOfDay());
        calendarNotifiedTime2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime2.getMinuteOfHour());
        calendarNotifiedTime2.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime2.getSecondOfMinute());
        calendarNotifiedTime2.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        final DateTime dateTime3 = DateTime.now();
        dateTime3.hourOfDay().setCopy(6);
        dateTime3.minuteOfHour().setCopy(30);
        dateTime3.secondOfMinute().setCopy(00);
        final Calendar calendarNotifiedTime3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarNotifiedTime3.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime3.getHourOfDay());
        calendarNotifiedTime3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime3.getMinuteOfHour());
        calendarNotifiedTime3.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime3.getSecondOfMinute());
        calendarNotifiedTime3.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(EmptyActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent1.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Repeat " + dateTime1.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime1.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime1.getSecondOfMinute());
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(EmptyActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent2.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Repeat " + dateTime2.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime2.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime2.getSecondOfMinute());
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(EmptyActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent3.putExtra(NotificationReceiver.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, "Repeat " + dateTime3.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime3.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime3.getSecondOfMinute());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EmptyActivity.this, REPEAT_NOTIFICATION1, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EmptyActivity.this, REPEAT_NOTIFICATION2, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EmptyActivity.this, REPEAT_NOTIFICATION3, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


                cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarNotifiedTime1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);
                cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION2);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarNotifiedTime2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);
                cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION3);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendarNotifiedTime3.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent3);
    }
```

Cancel Notification:

```
 public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
            try {
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

BroadCast Receiver:

```
   public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "notificationMessage";
    public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION1 = 201;
    public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION2 = 202;
    public static int REPEAT_NOTIFICATION3 = 203;

    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        this.context = context;

        //Assume StartDate = yesterday.
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.now().minusDays(1);
        //Assume EndDate = tomorrow
        DateTime endDate = startDate.plusDays(2);

        DateTime today = DateTime.now();

        if (today.isBefore(endDate) || today.isEqual(endDate)) {

            String message = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            //Define sound URI
            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EmptyActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            final DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
            int color = 0xffffaa00;
//        int color1 = context.getColor(R.color.notificatinBackgroundColor);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.festi_push_message_small);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setContentTitle("Notification Sample");
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setContentText(message + ", Current Time : " + dateTime.getHourOfDay() + ":" + dateTime.getMinuteOfHour() + ":" + dateTime.getSecondOfMinute());
            builder.setSound(soundUri);
            builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000);
            builder.setColor(color);

            Notification notification = builder.build();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            notificationManager.notify(102938, notification);
        } else {
            cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION1);
            cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION2);
            cancelNotification(REPEAT_NOTIFICATION3);
        }
    }

    public void cancelNotification(int requestCode) {
        try {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
```

Comment: Hi @Sabir can you show me the code for the DateTime.java?

Comment: Hi @Sabari i tried with the code but i don't seem to get the notification, also will this help me in setting event alarms for every events that i create??

Comment: Hi @WaseemAkram, Here I am using Joda DateTime

Comment: I am getting the tone but cant see the notified message. Also will this code work for multiple events? i mean i want the alarm to invoke for more than one event with same or different date and timings

Comment: Aslo i want to get the alarm daily till it reaches the end date.

Comment: Yes, it will repeat the alarm daily till the end date.

Comment: i tried with the code, but i dont seem to get the notification, also i m not sure how will i invoke the alarm daily, as the values for date and are dynamic i.e, selected by the user and not sure if i can be able to check the date like what u did in Broadcast Receiver class

Comment: Really I confused, I not sure, how is your app working and what are you expecting. Could you share your project with me?

Comment: Sure where u want me to share the project?

Comment: Could you share it in Github? or any other alternative which one is convenient for you.

Comment: if u can give me your mail id it u'd be better

Comment: sabariferin@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks Very much!!